# Django app url for media

Tags: python, django

I created and ImageField model for my blog app in my "test" django project on my local server using sqllite.

I have in my settings.py

`MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/me/Sites/python/djangotut/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/photos/'`

and my blog/models.py

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/photos/')
```

but the problem is my blog.urls.py I dont know how to add the url to work with my patterns thats in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .views import index, post


urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^$',
        view=index,
        name='blog-index'
    ),
    url(
        regex=r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$',
        view=post,
        name='blog-detail'
    ),

]
```

Also I have read something about urls being setup for a "production environment" for when you distribute apps. What would my urls need to look like in that case?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**.Have a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/ .

models.py

```
UPLOAD_PATH = "photos"
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=UPLOAD_PATH)
```

settings.py

```
from path import path
PROJECT_DIR = path(__file__).dirname().parent
MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for very similar to your answer. Specifically the MEDIA_ROOT, and MEDIA_URL in settings are not exact urls.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^newsletter/', include('newsletter.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py stayed the same.

Comment: Kinda the same like my answer! Hope it helped :)